# Disable fn functions on keyboard only for a key

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I was wondering if anyone could tell me how to disable the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key on my laptop only for <kbd>F1</kbd>, since other <kbd>Fn</kbd> functions are useful for me?

Comment: What does fn+F1 do on your laptop? On mine it toggles built-in display and external monitor. Although I have an external TV I never use the key. Ubuntu let me remap the key using the technique listed by @Hershy Gamer however acpi intercepts it at a lower level and still toggles the screens and messes up my sound :

Comment: F1 desploy the ubunu guide, something not relevant for me and fn+F1 is the usual F1

Answer (score 0):

Go to System. Click on control center. Click on keyboard shourtcuts, find the keys you want to disable and double click it. Another way to do it is to hold down <kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>ESC</kbd>.

Comment: He wanted to disable it not assign it to a short cut...

Comment: Sorry about that  I'll change it